# How to seprate data from database in php with if condition?

Tags: php, mysql

In my database there is a row in which there are some data strings are stored with separation of comma(,). And i want to show data on website with if condition. If there are more than 2 data strings.

```
if($row['category'] > 2){
  echo 'All Category';
}else{
  echo '.$row['category'].';
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `if(count(explode(',', $row['category'])) > 2) {`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do:

```
if(count(explode(',', $row['category'])) { 
   echo 'All Category'; 
} else {
   echo count(explode(',', $row['category']);
}
```

Comment: So where is **more than two-part**?

Comment: "just do" — Good answers explain what they changed and why. Games of spot-the-difference which then require all the changes to be looked up in the manual aren't great.